# Bash execute a for loop while time is outside working hours

Tags: bash, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to make the below script to execute a Restore binary between hours 17:00 - 07:00 for each folders which name starts with EAR_* in /backup_local/ARCHIVES/ but for some reason it is not working as expected, meaning that the for loop is not breaking if the time condition gets invalid.

Should I add the while loop inside the for loop?

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
#set -x



while :; do
 currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
 if [[ "$currenttime" > "17:00" ]] || [[ "$currenttime" < "07:00" ]]; then
 for path in /backup_local/ARCHIVES/EAR_*; do
     [ -d "${path}" ] || continue # if not a directory, skip
     dirname="$(basename "${path}")"
     nohup /Restore -a /backup_local/ARCHIVES -c -I 0 -force -v > /backup_local/$dirname.txt &
     wait $!
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         rm -rf $path
         rm /backup_local/$dirname.txt
         echo $dirname >> /backup_local/completed.txt
     fi
 done &
else
  echo "Restore can be ran only outside working hours!"
  break
fi
done &
```

Comment: i don't see anything in your `for` loop that would make it exit in the time condition. why do you think it should exit? what is the `while` loop supposed to do?

Comment: While is supposed to execute the for loop if currenttime is between 5 PM - 7 AM.

Comment: that's what it does. in a loop. so it keeps calling the for loop (which in turn will restore; and restore; and restore) until it's 7AM. then it exits.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I will re-test it today and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

your script looks like this in pseudo-code:

```
START
IF outside workinghours
    EXIT
ELSE
    RUN /Restore FOR EACH backupdir
GOTO START
```

The script only checks the time once, before starting a `restore` run (which will call `/Restore` for each directory to restore in a `for` loop)
It will continue to start the `for` loop, until the working hours start. Then it will exit.

E.g. if you have restore 3 folders to restore, each taking 2 hours; and you start the script at midnight; then the script will check whether it's outside working hours (it is), and will start the restore for the first folder (at `0:00`), after two hours of work it will start the restore the 2nd folder (at `2:00`), after another two hours it will start the restore of the 3rd folder (at `4:00`). Once the 3rd folder has been restored, it will check the working hours again. Since it's now only `6:00`, that is: outside the working hours, it will start the restore for the first folder (at `6:00`), after two hours of work it will start the restore the 2nd folder (at `8:00`), after another two hours it will start the restore of the 3rd folder (at `10:00`).
It's noon when it does the next check against the working hours; since `12:00` falls within `7:00`..`17:00`, the script will now stop. With an error message.

You probably only want the restore to run once for each folder, and stop proceeding to the next folder if the working hours start.

```
#!/bin/bash
for path in /backup_local/ARCHIVES/EAR_*/; do
  currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
  if [[ "$currenttime" > "7:00" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "17:00" ]]; then
      echo "Not restoring inside working hours!" 1>&2
      break
  fi
  dirname="$(basename "${path}")"
  /Restore -a /backup_local/ARCHIVES -c -I 0 -force -v > /backup_local/$dirname.txt
  # handle exit code
done
```

### update

I've just noticed your liberal spread of `&` for backgrounding jobs.
This is presumably to allow running the script from a remote shell. **don't**

What this will really do is:

1. it will run all the iterations over the restore-directories in parallel. This might create a bottleneck on your storage (if the directories to restore to/from share the same hardware)
2. it will background the entire loop-to-restore and immediately return to the out-of-hours check. if the check succeeds, it will spawn *another* loop-to-restore (and background it). then it will return to the out-of-hours check and spawn *another* backgrounded loop-to-restore.
   Before dawn you probably have a few thousands background threads to restore directories. More likely you've exceeded your ressources and the process get's killed.

My example script above has omitted all the backgrounding (and the `nohup)`.

If you want to run the script from a remote shell (and exit the shell after launching it), just run it with

```
nohup restore-script.sh &
```

Alternatively you could use

```
echo "restore-script.sh" | at now
```

or use a cron-job (if applicable)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, in fact your code is running the Restore process inside of working hours, I want to run it outside of working hours so I've changed the condition back to `if [[ "$currenttime" > "17:00" ]] || [[ "$currenttime" < "07:00" ]]; then`. I wil give it a go and let you know.

Comment: nope. my code does an early exit if within working hours. so it's "if within working hours, exit; else run the restore" instead of your "if not within working hours run restore; else exit". it does have a wrong error message though, which i'll fix immediately.

Comment: Actually I've tried this and I can confirm it does not auto exists if time gets > 7:00 AM.

Comment: depends on what you mean with "auto exists". If you mean the loop should immediately stop at 7:00am, then you are right, this is not the case. what it does is to stop looping at 7:00am (after `/Restore` has returned).

Comment: also note that the `/Restore` command has no (direct) argument to know that it should currently backup `$directory`. most probably it just restores the entire `ARCHIVES` folder in each loop (rather than just `ARCHIVES/EAR_0001/`)

Answer (score -1):

The shebang contains an unwanted space. On my ubuntu the `bash` is found at `/bin/bash`.

Yours, is located there :

```
type bash
```

The while loop breaks in my test, replace the `#!/bin/bash` path with the result of the previous command:

```
#!/bin/bash --
#set -x

while : ; do
 currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
 if [[ "$currenttime" > "17:00" ]] || [[ "$currenttime" < "07:00" ]]; then
   for path in /backup_local/ARCHIVES/EAR_*; do
     [ -d "${path}" ] || continue # if not a directory, skip
     dirname="$(basename "${path}")"
     nohup /Restore -a /backup_local/ARCHIVES -c -I 0 -force -v > /backup_local/$dirname.txt &
     wait $!
     if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
         rm -rf $path
         rm /backup_local/$dirname.txt
         echo $dirname >> /backup_local/completed.txt
     fi
   done &
 else
   echo "Restore can be ran only outside working hours!"
   break
 fi
done &
```

Comment: the leading space is [irrelevant for the shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276751); the location of `bash` might well be in `/usr/bin` (e.g. on a [UsrMerge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) system), get it with `which bash`; the OP seems to be able to run the script fine, it's the logic that fails.

Comment: Thank you, It seems I've missed that space. I am using AIX so my bash is in /usr/bin/bash.

Comment: @Mihaimyh: on my ubuntu the `IF` statement was alright and the `WHILE` loop was breaking as expected. After the changes, did it worked?